# Multi Part Identifier Could Not Be Bound: Multiple Joins with Select

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm trying to run a query which will return a list of tickets that are open and resolved from our ticketing system by engineer for reporting services.

We currently have a query which does this, without the engineer being attached; so I'm trying to work back from this, and I think I'm almost there, but I'm encountering an issue (I'm fairly new to SQL)

The Error I'm receiving is *Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
The multi-part identifier "au.FIRST_NAME" could not be bound.*

I think this is as I've included the joins for wos.OWNERID and au.USER_ID within other joins, but when attempting to use a Left Outer Join after all the other's, or before, I then get the error for incorrect syntax on the last Where Statement.

Relevant Table Details are as follows:

**AAAUSER TABLE**

```
USER_ID     FIRST_NAME
1           System
2           $DEPT_HEAD$
3           Guest
```

**WORKORDERSTATES TABLE**

```
WORKORDERID OWNERID
226     84161
521297      84161
521968      94
```

**Query Below** (Note, every table excluding "Date Dimension" is in the ServiceDesk Database, as opposed to the ServiceDeskExtras Database at the beginning of the query.

```
select
    dd.[Date] 'Date'
    ,format(dd.date,'dd/MM/yyyy','en-gb') 'DisplayDate'
    ,Logged.Tickets 'Tickets Logged'
    ,Closed.Tickets 'Tickets Resolved'
    ,count(OpenTickets.Tickets) 'Open Tickets'
    ,au.FIRST_NAME 'Technician'
from
    ServiceDeskExtras.dbo.DateDimension dd
    left join (
        select
            convert(date,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,wo.CREATEDTIME)/1000,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970'))) 'Date'
            ,count(wo.workorderid) 'Tickets'
        from
            WorkOrder wo
            join AccountSiteMapping asm on wo.SITEID = asm.SITEID
            join AccountDefinition ad on asm.ACCOUNTID = ad.ORG_ID
            left join WORKORDERDELETEHISTORY wodh on wo.WORKORDERID = wodh.WORKORDERID
            join WorkOrderStates wos on wo.WORKORDERID = wos.WORKORDERID
            join AaaUser au on wos.OWNERID = au.USER_ID
            join PriorityDefinition pd on wos.PRIORITYID = pd.PRIORITYID
            join requesttypedefinition rtd on wos.requesttypeid = rtd.requesttypeid
            --join SDOrganization sdo on wo.SITEID = sdo.ORG_ID
            --join SiteDefinition sd on wo.SITEID = sd.SITEID
            --join RegionDefinition rd on sd.REGIONID = rd.REGIONID
        where
            ad.ORG_NAME = 'CUSTOMER NAME'
            and pd.PRIORITYNAME in ('P1','P2','P3','P4')
            and wodh.WORKORDERID is null
            and rtd.name <> 'Automatic Monitoring'
        group by
            convert(date,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,wo.CREATEDTIME)/1000,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970')))
    ) Logged on dd.[Date] = Logged.Date
    left join (
        select
            convert(date,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,wo.resolvedtime)/1000,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970'))) 'Date'
            ,count(wo.workorderid) 'Tickets'
        from
            WorkOrder wo
            join AccountSiteMapping asm on wo.SITEID = asm.SITEID
            join AccountDefinition ad on asm.ACCOUNTID = ad.ORG_ID
            left join WORKORDERDELETEHISTORY wodh on wo.WORKORDERID = wodh.WORKORDERID
            join WorkOrderStates wos on wo.WORKORDERID = wos.WORKORDERID
            join AaaUser au on wos.OWNERID = au.USER_ID
            join PriorityDefinition pd on wos.PRIORITYID = pd.PRIORITYID
            join requesttypedefinition rtd on wos.requesttypeid = rtd.requesttypeid
            --join SDOrganization sdo on wo.SITEID = sdo.ORG_ID
            --join SiteDefinition sd on wo.SITEID = sd.SITEID
            --join RegionDefinition rd on sd.REGIONID = rd.REGIONID
        where
            ad.ORG_NAME = 'CUSTOMER NAME'
            and pd.PRIORITYNAME in ('P1','P2','P3','P4')
            and wodh.WORKORDERID is null
            and rtd.name <> 'Automatic Monitoring'
        group by
            convert(date,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,wo.resolvedtime)/1000,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970')))
    ) Closed on dd.date = Closed.Date
    left join (
        select
            wo.workorderid 'Tickets'
            ,dateadd(s,wo.CREATEDTIME/1000,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970')) 'Logged'
            ,dateadd(s,wo.resolvedtime/1000,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970')) 'Resolved'
        from
            workorder wo
            join AccountSiteMapping asm on wo.SITEID = asm.SITEID
            join AccountDefinition ad on asm.ACCOUNTID = ad.ORG_ID
            left join WORKORDERDELETEHISTORY wodh on wo.WORKORDERID = wodh.WORKORDERID
            join WorkOrderStates wos on wo.WORKORDERID = wos.WORKORDERID
            join AaaUser au on wos.OWNERID = au.USER_ID
            join PriorityDefinition pd on wos.PRIORITYID = pd.PRIORITYID
            join requesttypedefinition rtd on wos.requesttypeid = rtd.requesttypeid
            --join SDOrganization sdo on wo.SITEID = sdo.ORG_ID
            --join SiteDefinition sd on wo.SITEID = sd.SITEID
            --join RegionDefinition rd on sd.REGIONID = rd.REGIONID
        where
            ad.ORG_NAME = 'CUSTOMER NAME'
            and pd.PRIORITYNAME in ('P1','P2','P3','P4')
            and wodh.WORKORDERID is null
            and rtd.name <> 'Automatic Monitoring'
    ) OpenTickets on dateadd(dd,1,dd.date) > OpenTickets.Logged and (dateadd(dd,1,dd.date) <= OpenTickets.Resolved or datediff(dd,convert(datetime,'1-1-1970'),opentickets.resolved) = 0)

where
    dd.[Date] >= dateadd(d,-7,@date)
    and dd.[Date] < @date
group by
     dd.[Date]
     ,logged.Tickets
     ,closed.Tickets
order by
    dd.[Date]
```

The expected outcome would be for Technicians to list in the same column so that I can add to the report Tickets Logged vs Resolved by Technician.

Any help is greatly appreciated - I'm keen to understand where I would need to place this within the query, so that I know in future how to format this correctly!

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 0):

I think you are little bit confused witha query you have and result you want achive.

1. You put au.FIRST_NAME 'Technician' in global SELECT list which cause MS SQL to fail and that's correct because there are no such alias in global FROM. Global From knows only about following datasets: dd, Logged, Closed and OpenTickets. So no au exists here.
2. au.FIRST_NAME can be accessed only on subquery level of each left join ()
3. You current left join doesn't expose au.FIRST_NAME to global FROM because they are not included in SELECT list of each left join. To include them in SELECT list of each left join you have to put them also in GROUP BY clause.
4. But still if you implement previous point you cannot have only one FIRST_NAME 'Technician' for three left joins you do because in this scenario you'll have 3 FIRST_NAMEs for each left join: Logged.FIRST_NAME, Closed.FIRST_NAME, OpenTickets.FIRST_NAME.

If you want to see Closed and Opened tickets per technician then, I think, you should get technician data (user_id, name) from Logged join and then use user_id to join over opened and closed joins but keep in mind that user_id should appear in select list and group by clause of each subquery